# Chaining haproxys with optimal connection re-use and keep-alive

Tags: haproxy

I need to understand the optimal connection configurations for chaining 2 haproxys to provide maximum connection reuse between the edge proxy, the app proxy and the app containers.

Where should I be correctly using `http-server-close`,  `http-reuse` or `keep-alive` settings?

I have haproxy instances sitting in edge regions which proxy over private networks to a central data center where another haproxy provides the application routing based on url paths to application containers.  All application containers are completely stateless rest servers.

The setup is as follows:

```
haproxy-edge(s) -> haproxy-app(s) -> app-component(s)
```

Each haproxy-edge serves thousands of concurrent browser and api connections and does ssl offloading etc.

haproxy-app can only be reached via connections from haproxy-edge and does path routing, sets consistent response headers etc.

haproxy-edge connection settings

```
defaults
  mode http
  option redispatch
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option log-health-checks
  option http-ignore-probes
  option http-server-close
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 15s
  timeout server 300s
  timeout http-keep-alive 4s
  timeout http-request 10s
  timeout tunnel 2m
  timeout client-fin 1s
  timeout server-fin 1s
  ...
backend ...
# Routes to haproxy-app. No backend specific connection settings at all
```

haproxy-app connection settings

```
defaults
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option redispatch
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option http-ignore-probes
  option http-server-close
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 15s
  timeout server 300s
  #timeout http-keep-alive 4s
  timeout http-request 10s
  timeout tunnel 2m
  timeout client-fin 1s
  timeout server-fin 1s
frontend http-in
  ...
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  option http-server-close
  ...
backend ...
# Routes to app components. No backend specific connection settings at all
```

I see no reuse of connections in haproxy stats page and the number of sessions/connections seems to be similar at both haproxys, but would expect many on edge to fewer reused connections in haproxy-app.

Answer (score 1):

After testing various combinations the simple (and obvious) change of removing `option http-server-close` from both haproxy-edge and haproxy-app allowed the connection reuse to work effectively.  Haproxy 2.x has some nice new stats page values for reporting on new v's reused connections.